Resolving gravitational acceleration
I came across a problem in physics where I had to find the acceleration down an inclined plane. I started by considering $g$ as one of the components, and the one along the inclined plane as the actual vector. But I came up with a wrong answer. My question is: if a vector can be resolved along any vector, then why can't the acceleration down the inclined plane be resolved in the above mentioned way?

Instead of considering $\mathbf{g}$ as one of the components of some vector $\mathbf{v}$ along the inclined plane, you should try your calculations again but treating $\mathbf{v}$ as a component of $\mathbf{g}$. That is, the gravitational acceleration vector should be the hypotenuse of your triangle. Doing so, you will find that this decomposition works as expected.

Imagine pushing a box horizontally to the left on flat ground. It surely has an acceleration vector towards the left since you are speeding it up. But it has no acceleration vector downwards. So, the gravitational acceleration clearly cannot be one of its vector components.*
The reason for this is that acceleration is cause by each influencing force. Acceleration is only ever caused by the sum of all influencing force. This is Newton's 2nd law, $$\sum \vec F=m\vec a.$$
There are several forces involved in this scenario. Your pushing force towards the left $F_\text{push}$, perhaps a kinetic friction force towards the right $f_k$, the downwards gravitational force (the weight) $w$, and an upwards normal force from the ground $n$. These forces do not each cause an acceleration. Only their sum causes an acceleration.
So, there is no gravitational acceleration caused by this gravitational force in this case. The gravitational acceleration just represents what gravity would have caused, had there been no other forces interferring (so in a free fall). Sure, the gravitational acceleration parameter $g$ is involved in how you can calculate the gravitational force, but still, it is not necessarily involved in the resulting acceleration at all, as my example above shows.

* Now, with all this being said, it actually is possible to consider the gravitational acceleration vector as a component of the resulting acceleration of your object. But only if you then include the imagined acceleration components of all forces that are involved. They will constitute all components, that all together will add up to the actual acceleration of your object. But I personally find it more fruitful and intuitive to go with the above-mentioned way of thinking.

While others gave the correct hints how to solve this problem, I'll try to discuss the reasoning that maybe misled you, and how a correct reasoning could be achieved.
You can always add some mathematical vectors, but that does not imply that the result has any useful physical meaning. So it's important to know why and when a vector addition has a physical meaning, and what this meaning is.
Your assumption seems to be that the resulting acceleration of a body is a sum of various different influencing accelerations. But there is no such physical law, and it is even problematic to define what such "influencing accelerations" should be, as a body only has one acceleration (and not multiple ones), describing some aspect of the path that it moves along.
What you can usefully add, are forces. The resulting force exerted on a body is the vector sum of all individual forces, and this resulting force determines the acceleration of the body.
So, before diving into any calculations, some reasoning about the setting is important:

There is the gravitational force acting on the body, pulling downwards.
There is an (unknown-value) supporting force, exerted be the inclined surface, directed perpendicular to the surface. As the surface is not sticky, it cannot pull on the object, meaning that the supporting force cannot be negative.
As it is not mentioned explicitly, I assume that there is no friction force (which would act parallel to the surface).
Any resulting acceleration will be parallel to the inclined plane (the body will neither dive into the plane nor lift off).
By physical law, any resulting acceleration has the same direction as the vector sum of forces.
So (the other way round), we come to the conclusion that the sum of forces must be parallel to the inclined surface.
The value of the supporting force must be such that the vector sum of the gravitational plus the supporting force has a direction parallel to the surface.

After drawing a vector diagram of the forces, you see that the resulting force can be found from decomposing the gravitational force into one component along the surface and one perpendicular to the surface, and keeping just the one along the surface.
Mathematically, you can divide all these force vectors by the body's mass, so that mathematically (from their dimension units) they all look like accelerations, and reformulate the result as:

The resulting acceleration is the component of the "gravitational acceleration" parallel to the surface.

I'm using quotes around the word "gravitational acceleration", as in our setting there isn't a single body that accelerates like that, so this is more of a hypothetical value, and not a real acceleration.
Advanced remark: In unusual cases, it might turn out that we need a negative supporting force to solve the vector math. But as our surface can only support the body and not pull on it, we'd then have to throw away our calculation (it was based on false assumptions), and restart our reasoning with a zero supporting force and no constraint on the overall acceleration direction. This will happen with inclinations beyond 90 degrees and simply result in a free fall.
